# Getting the first class from multiple classes with the same name with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract information from [this page](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/) which has it's HTML as below.

I am trying to extract the text in the first `class="currentServers"` (example: I get **745,807** from this line `<span class="currentServers">745,807</span>`

The problem is that in the row there are two spans with class name `class="currentServers"`. I want to get the value in the first column of the row.

HTML:

```
<tr class="player_count_row" style="">
                            <td align="right">
                                <span class="currentServers">745,807</span>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <span class="currentServers">836,540</span>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="gameLink" onmouseover="GameHover( this, event, 'global_hover', {&quot;type&quot;:&quot;app&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:570,&quot;v6&quot;:1} );" onmouseout="HideGameHover( this, event, 'global_hover' )" href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/570/">Dota 2</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

I feel that I am close but I can't figure it out.

This is what I tried:

```
def GetTopGamesByPlayers():
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    r = []

    final_link = soup.p.a
    final_link.decompose()

    links = soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "gameLink" })
    currentPlayers = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "currentServers"})

    players = ""
    i = 0

    for player in currentPlayers :
        for link in links:
            players = currentPlayers[0].text
            try:
                appid = link.get('onmouseover')
                appid = findAppIdFromStats(appid,'"id":' , ',"public":1')
                linkg = link.get('href')
            except AttributeError:
                r.append(["N/A","N/A","N/A"])  
            r.append([appid,linkg,players])

    c = ["N/A","N/A", "N/A"]
    while c in r:
        r.remove(c)
    return r

def findAppIdFromStats( s, first, last ):
      try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
      except ValueError:
            return "first: " + first + "last: " + last
```

The below is the output :

```
[u'346110', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/346110/', u'745,807']
[u'230410', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/230410/', u'745,807']
[u'252950', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/252950/', u'745,807']
[u'482730', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/482730/', u'745,807']
[u'252490', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/252490/', u'745,807']
[u'4000', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/4000/', u'745,807']
[u'444090', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/444090/', u'745,807']
[u'359550', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/359550/', u'745,807']
[u'588430', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/588430/', u'745,807']
[u'374320', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/374320/', u'745,807']
[u'8930', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/', u'745,807']
[u'107410', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/107410/', u'745,807']
[u'238960', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/238960/', u'745,807']
[u'304930', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/304930/', u'745,807']
[u'10', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/', u'745,807']
[u'72850', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/72850/', u'745,807']
[u'289070', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/289070/', u'745,807']
[u'105600', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/105600/', u'745,807']
[u'377160', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/377160/', u'745,807']
[u'236390', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/236390/', u'745,807']
[u'292030', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/292030/', u'745,807']
[u'227300', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/227300/', u'745,807']
[u'386360', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/386360/', u'745,807']
[u'236850', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/236850/', u'745,807']
[u'364360', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/364360/', u'745,807']
[u'381210', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/381210/', u'745,807']
[u'363970', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/363970/', u'745,807']
[u'453480', u'http://store.steampowered.com/app/453480/', u'745,807'

... ... ...
```

I want to extract the value that has the red ellipse around it:

(appid, Current Players, Game Name) - I can succesfully get the appid and game name for each game but not the Current Players in sequence

[image]

Comment: [I wrote a small framework](https://github.com/Wykleph/selenext) on top of selenium for web scraping, but it supports using selenium's syntax to look up elements using Requests, BeautifulSoup and lxml, you just can't interact with web pages like you can with selenium.  Here is a [link to the docs](https://github.com/Wykleph/selenext/wiki/Documentation#requests-webreader).  I think it might help you with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by amending the code as below:

```
links = soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "gameLink" })
    currentPlayers = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "currentServers"})

    players = ""

    rows = soup.findAll("tr", { "class" : "player_count_row" })    

    for row in rows:
        players = row.findAll("span", { "class" : "currentServers" })[0].text
        for link in links:
                try:
                    appid = link.get('onmouseover')
                    appid = findAppIdFromStats(appid,'"id":' , ',"public":1')
                    linkg = link.get('href')
                except AttributeError:
                    r.append(["N/A","N/A","N/A"])  
        r.append([appid,linkg,players])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try grabbing each of the rows and then grabbing the first instance of `.currentServers` like this.

```
rows = soup.find_all(class_='player_count_row')
for row in rows:
    print row.find(class_='currentServers').text
```

Comment: There are two divs called 'currentServers' in the same row. How do I filter them to only get the first one?

Comment: It will automatically only grab the first one when you use `find()`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you are using two loops?

If not you can try with one loop and when looping the link, find the previous `tr` and then the first `td` which contains the player number that you want.

Example:

```
for link in links:
        players = currentPlayers[0].text
        try:
            appid = link.get('onmouseover')
            appid = findAppIdFromStats(appid,'"id":' , ',"public":1')
            linkg = link.get('href')
        except AttributeError:
            r.append(["N/A","N/A","N/A"])
        r.append([appid, linkg, link.find_previous("tr", class_="player_count_row").find("td").get_text(strip=True)])
```

Comment: I am using two loops because I have to first loop all games and then loop all the current players. The code you supplied return this error: `'NoneType' object is not callable` on this line `r.append([appid, linkg, link.find_previous("tr", class_="player_count_row").find("td").get_text(strip=True)])`